# Vim Custom Replace Function

Tags: vim, replace, vi, neovim

Note: I'm currently using Neovim v0.2.2 (But I believe this shouldn't change anything related this post)

I'm currently attempting to create a function within vim that allows for easily replacing text.

I understand I can create a shortcuts and macros and all that, but ideally I just want to give 2 args, and not think about what specifics go where as this can interupt my thought process.

So I decided to just have a simple wrapper disguised as a function (Which I will create a command wrapper for as well, once I figure out what I did wrong here)

```
function! VisualReplace(query, replacement)
" Example = '<,'>s/query\%V/replacement/g
'<,'>s/a:query\%V/a:replacement/g
endfunction
```

As you can see, it's a very simple function that just applies the args in it's respective position, Yet, this fails even when called as a function using : `call VisualReplace('some_query', 'some_replacement'`

Alternatively, if you simply use the Example I have commented out directly, there's no issue, So I was hoping someoen could enlighten me on a potential fix

If need be, I could possibly look into string building & build it incrementally

Error msg: 
Pattern not found: a:query\%V

Comment: this coul help you: https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/11503/substitute-variable-into-match/11504#11504 You will have to use execute and string concatination to merge your command with the variables.

Answer (score 4):

#### General theory

Vimscript is evaluated exactly like the Ex commands typed in the `:` command-line. There were no variables in `ex`, so there's no way to specify them. When typing a command interactively, you'd probably use `<C-R>=` to insert variable contents:

```
:sleep <C-R>=timetowait<CR>m<CR>
```

... but in a script, `:execute` must be used. All the literal parts of the Ex command must be quoted (single or double quotes), and then concatenated with the variables:

```
execute 'sleep' timetowait . 'm'
```

#### Your function

In order to get the `a:query` and `a:replacement` arguments into `:substitute`, use `:execute` and either *string concatenation* or `printf()`:

```
function! VisualReplace(query, replacement)
    execute "'<,'>s/" . a:query . '\%V/' . a:replacement . '/g'
endfunction
```

#### Additional critique

Passing a range to a function is so common, there's special syntactic sugar for it: The `range` attribute to `:function`, and `a:firstline` and `a:lastline` implicit arguments. Read more about it at `:help function-range-example`. While your use case here seems to be specifically for visual mode, in general it's useful to keep the scope of functions as broad as possible.

Answer (score 1):

@Ingo Karkat answered perfectly. However, I feel like there might be some workflow alternatives which might help. (Assuming you aren't trying to script this behavior)

#### Visual Star

It looks like you are build a search based on a visual section. You may want to consider using a [visual-star plugin](https://vimawesome.com/?q=star) to simplify the process. Here is a an example of a visual star mapping:

```
xnoremap * :<c-u>let @/=@"<cr>gvy:let [@/,@"]=[@",@/]<cr>/\V<c-r>=substitute(escape(@/,'/\'),'\n','\\n','g')<cr><cr>
```

This mapping will allow you to visually select text and then execute `*` to make it a search pattern. Similar to how `*` works in normal mode on the current `word`.

#### Search refining

I get the impression that you are trying to refine your search pattern. Vim has a nice way of doing this with `q/` or pressing `<c-f>` while searching with `/`. See `:h q/`. This will bring up the command-line window which will allow you to edit the query/command-line with all your normal Vim keys.

#### Search and Replace with `gn` motion

Sometimes doing a substitution is just overkill or doesn't quite fit the situation right. You can mimic a search and replace by using the `gn` motion to operate on a search pattern. By using an operator and the `gn` motion together you can use the dot command, `.`, to repeat the action easily.

Example:

```
/foo
cgnbar<esc>
```

Now you can use `.` to repeat the `foo` -> `bar` replacement. Use `n` to skip. You can use other operators as well, e.g. `gU` to uppercase.

See `:h gn` and `:h operator` for more help.

#### Related [Vimcasts](http://vimcasts.org/) episodes:

- [Refining search patterns with the command-line window](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/refining-search-patterns-with-the-command-line-window/)
- [Operating on search matches using `gn`](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/operating-on-search-matches-using-gn/)
- [Search for the selected text](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/search-for-the-selected-text/)